# Передает ли Input Method Service какой либо intent

Tags: java, android

Добрый день! Задача вот в чем: необходимо запустить сервис или активность при вызове клавиатуры в другом приложении. Думаю единственный способ это зацепиться за Input Method Service который запускается при вызове клавиатуры. Возможно ли это или есть другой способ?

Comment: откровенно попахивает каким то вирусным приложением. если это не так, то напишите для каких целей вам это необходимо.

Comment: Когда начал изучать эту тему сам дошел до мысли что разработчики ОС  андроид намеренно ограничили доступ к действиям клавиатуры чтобы не "натворить делов"). Нет, не вирусное, а например доступ к смайликам в любом приложении. Решить мою задачу можно реализовав NotificationListenerService